# how to add post date to telegram plugin content?

Tags: function, telegram

i have a telegram plugin to send posts automaticaly to channel.
this is a part of publish function of plugin:

```
   $type = get_post_meta ($post_ID,'tchannel_select',true);
   if ($type == 'contenttext'){
        $content_post = get_post($post_ID);
        $content = $content_post->post_content;
        if ($link == 'glass') {
       $message = $content;
        } else {
       $message = $url.chr(10).$content;
        }
   } elseif ($type == 'customtext'){
       if ($link == 'glass') { 
       $message = get_post_meta ($post_ID,'tchannel_text',true);
       } else {
       $message = $url.chr(10).get_post_meta ($post_ID,'tchannel_text',true);
       }   
   }
```

now i want to add post date and some costume text to end of contents.

Comment: Just concatenate them to `$content`. What's the problem?

Comment: how can i concatenate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this plugin havn't query.  you should edit manualy
just adjust to:
        `$content = substr($content, 0, 200); 
          $message = $content.' costume text ';
           $message = $url.chr(10).$content.' costume text ';`